# Hashing of a file

Tags: hash

Which programming language is best for hashing a file ? 
Which language is more faster in hashing a file ?
I am currently searching for a language that helps me to do hash of files soon and has less time complexity.
Please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a very large file, you have to make it into parts. Calculate the digest for first part and pass it to next. Follow the same for all the successive intermediate hashes for all the parts. You can use java.security.MessageDigest.clone(), do hash calculation and then call digest().

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Python, since python libraries are available

Below code is for MD5 hashing.

```
import hashlib

hasher = hashlib.md5()
with open('myfile.jpg', 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read()
    hasher.update(buf)
print(hasher.hexdigest())
```

And below code is for SHA1 hashing.

```
import hashlib
BLOCKSIZE = 65536
hasher = hashlib.sha1()
with open('anotherfile.txt', 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        hasher.update(buf)
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
print(hasher.hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation of SHA-1 and MD5 checksum:

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

File fileObj = new File("abc.jar");

//To use MD5 algo

MessageDigest mdMd5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

// To use SHA-1 algo

MessageDigest mdSha1  = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileObj);

byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

int readCount = 0;

while((readCount = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {

// For MD5
mdMd5.update(bytes, 0, readCount);

//For SHA-1

mdSha1.update(ytes,0,readCount);

};

fileInputStream.close();

//read md5 Hash bytes

byte[] md5HashBytes = mdMd5.digest();

//read sha-1 Hash bytes

byte[] sha1HashBytes = mdSha1.digest();

StringBuilder sbMd5 = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder sbSha1 = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i < md5HashBytes.length; i++) {

sbMd5.append(Integer.toString((md5HashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

}

System.out.println("MD5 checksum:");

System.out.println(sbMd5.toString());

for (int j=0;j < sha1HashBytes.length;j++) {

sbSha1.append(Integer.toString((sha1HashBytes[j] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

}

System.out.println("SHA-1 checksum:");
System.out.println(sbSha1.toString());

}